# why does the website know i am using a bot to check my ip

Tags: mechanize

I use mechanize to create a virtual browser

```
        br = mechanize.Browser()

        # set cookies
        cookies = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
        br.set_cookiejar(cookies)

        # browser settings (used to emulate a browser)
        br.set_handle_equiv(True)
        br.set_handle_redirect(True)
        br.set_handle_referer(True)
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        br.set_debug_http(False)
        br.set_debug_responses(False)
        br.set_debug_redirects(False)
        br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
        br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
        br.open("http://www.whatsmyip.org/")
```

Although the website returm my ip, they give a notice

```
Please DO NOT program a bot to use this site to grab your IPs. It kills my server and thats not nice. Just get some cheap or free web hosting and make your own IP-only page to power your bot. Then you won't even have to parse any html, just load the IP directly - better for everyone!!
```

Why does the website know that?
Do I miss something in my code?

Comment: So you're asking "How can I hide the fact that I am doing what they are explicitly asking me to NOT do?"  Why would you want to do that?  Why would we want to help you do that?

Comment: @AndyLester your're right, maybe he can use something like [this](http://api.exip.org/?call=ip). Or do you know any other options specifically for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, it all works fine.

Do you mean this part:

```
<!--
    Please DO NOT program a bot to use this site to grab your IPs. It kills my server and thats not nice.
    Just get some cheap or free web hosting and make your own IP-only page to power your bot.
    Then you won't even have to parse any html, just load the IP directly - better for everyone!!                               
-->
```

If yes, than it's just [comment tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp), that is used just to remind users not to use the website with bots.

It doesn't "catch" you or anything. If you will go to the [whatsmyip](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp) page and open the souse code you will see that it starts on the line 24 (even if you open it in the browser).

So all in all it's just a warning that wed-developers putter inside the HTML